# Unable to run two docker containers with docker-compose. I get the error: "python: can't open file 'app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run two web services in 2 separate containers, but unable to run them both at the same time. Separately they both work.

My project structure is this:

```
/
- docker-compose.yml
- Dockerfile
- pom.xml
- src/
- ... other spring boot web service folders and files
- Pirmas/
  -Dockerfile
  -app.py
  -docker-compose.yml (it is not used when running both services)
```

One web service is in the main directory the other is in the directory "Pirmas". I try to run docker composer from the base folder where the spring boot service is. I use the command "docker-compose up --build -d".

However, after building only the spring boot web service is launched and when I check the logs of the flask web service it says "python: can't open file 'app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

My spring boot service Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6-jdk-8 AS build  

WORKDIR /code

COPY src /code/app/src
COPY pom.xml /code/app
RUN mvn -f /code/app/pom.xml clean install

FROM openjdk:8
COPY --from=build /code/app/target/SpringWebServiceToDoList-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar SpringWebServiceToDoList-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["java","-jar","SpringWebServiceToDoList-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

My docker-compose.yml file in the same directory:

```
version: '3'

services:
  springboot-docker-compose-app-container:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:5000"
    depends_on:
    - friendservice
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    networks:
    - mynet
  friendservice:
    build: ./Pirmas
    command: python app.py
    ports:
    - 5000:5001
    networks:
    - mynet

networks:
    mynet:
```

My Dockerfile in the flash web service:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Lastly the docker-compose.yml which I assume is not used(from the flask web service directory "Pirmas"):

```
web:
  build: .
  command: python app.py
  ports:
    - "80:5000"
  volumes:
    - .:/code
```

What I tried:

I tried removing the volumes. Tried different paths in docker-compose.yml like python ./Pirmas/app.py

I would be grateful for any help or ideas.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I'm having a similar issue when trying to launch another project, but this time a Spring Boot application.

```
The project structure:/
    - docker-compose.yml
    - Dockerfile
    - pom.xml
    - src/
    - ... other spring boot web service folders and files
    - rest-bookstore/
      -Dockerfile
      -rest
        -src
        -target
          -gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar
```

The old Dockerfile of the first spring boot service is the same the new one is:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-alpine
COPY rest /rest
WORKDIR /rest
RUN mvn clean package
CMD java -jar target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar --server.port=5000
```

And the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  springboot-docker-compose-app-container:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:5000"
    depends_on:
    - friendservice
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    networks:
    - mynet
  friendservice:
    build: ./rest-bookstore
    volumes:
    - ./rest-bookstore:/rest
    ports:
    - 5000:5001
    networks:
    - mynet

networks:
    mynet:
```

I get error:

> Unable to access jarfile target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar

And I don't know why since in the new dockerfile it copies the whole rest directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `friendservice` doesn't have `app.py` inside. You should whether copy it so your Dockerfile looks like

```sh
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY app.py ./
```

Or you can attach volume in your `docker-compose.yml` so it looks like

```sh
...
  friendservice:
    build: ./Pirmas
    command: python app.py
    ports:
    - 5000:5001
    volumes:
    - ./Pirmas:/code
    networks:
    - mynet
...
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems now that it works using your 2nd suggested method. Just wanted to ask another question. Why did the python web service work separately on its own? Did the volumes:  - .:/code in the python web service docker-compose.yml file meant that it included the current directory and now I need to add the "Pirmas" like in your second method to include that directory instead?

Comment: Not sure I completely got your question. Your two services create two containers. These containers are connected only by shared networks and shared volumes. You haven't add any volumes to `friendservice`. That's why it doesn't know anything about `app.py`. If you add `volumes: - .:/code` to `friendservice`, you need to add `command: ruby Pirmas/app.`

Comment: What I meant is that the flask service alone worked on its own (see the last two code segments I posted). And if I understand correctly adding only volumes: - .:/code is not enough since the service is in a different directory now when having two services(without changing the command). Also, the friendservice is the one with the app.py building from ./Pirmas. So it is still not clear for me why do I need to add the volumes in friendservice itself.(is it for later building? running?).

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. You don't necessary need to use volume, you can just copy your `app.py` as in first example. But you may use volume. And volumes are shared between services only if implicitly mentioned in service description. See more info here https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

Comment: Alright, thank you for the help and clarification. :)

Comment: Sorry to bother again. I'm having another similiar issue I can't solve. I updated the question. Could you help?

Comment: Maybe you should better create another question as it's pretty different issues?

Comment: Alright I will. I will post the link here afterwards. Okay?

Comment: I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55733887/unable-to-run-two-spring-boot-services-with-docker-compose-error-unable-to-acc